# Firebase RecyclerView Displays One Item

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my database, I have entries with multiple songs. This is what it the DB looks like, and what is showing in the display:

```
  "DjSunGazer" : {
    "song" : {
      "-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2" : "Blaya - Cash",
      "-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI" : "Blaya - Cash",
      "-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz" : "Taylor Swift - You Need to Calm Down"
    }
  },
```

[image]

In my app, I was able to use a hashmap to assign each unique song with a counter. Now, in the Firebase RecyclerView Adapter it only shows the last entry in the database. Here is the code:

```
            query = mProfileDatabase.child(djName);

            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataSnapshot> firebaseRecyclerOptions =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSnapshot>()
                    .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<DataSnapshot>(){
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public DataSnapshot parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
                        {
                            return snapshot;
                        }
                    }).build();

            final HashMap<String, Integer> songCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSnapshot, ResultsViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions)
                    {

                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataSnapshot model)
                        {
                            List<String> sArr = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : model.getChildren())
                            {
                                sArr.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                            }


                            for(int i = 0; i < sArr.size(); i++)
                            {
                                String eachSong = sArr.get(i);
                                if(songCounts.containsKey(eachSong))
                                {
                                    int count = songCounts.get(eachSong);
                                    songCounts.put(eachSong, count + 1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    songCounts.put(eachSong, 1);
                                }
                            }

                            Collection<String> name = songCounts.keySet();
                            Collection<Integer> ctn = songCounts.values();

                            for(String s2 : name)
                            {
                                Log.d("INFO", s2);
                                DisplaySong ds = new DisplaySong(s2);
                                ds.setSong(s2);
                                holder.setDJNameView(ds);
                            }
                            for(Integer i : ctn)
                            {
                                holder.setBadgeCount(i);
                            }
                        }


                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                        {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.djname_item, viewGroup, false);
                            return new ResultsViewHolder(view);
                        }
                    };
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            songCounts.clear();
```

Instead of just the value showing in the recyclerview as "Rick Ross - Gold Roses (feat.Drake)" with a 1 badge saying theres only one occurrence in the DB, I want it to display "Ginuwine - So Anxious"(3) as well below that first entry. This has already been calculated and handled in my songCounts HashMap. Thanks!

EDIT *Added dj_name_item.xml*

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_result_dj"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_badge"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: *added how the data is being inserted*

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(djName).child("song").push().setValue(songName);
```

Comment: how about adding `R.layout.djname_item` (which I'd have under suspicion)?

Comment: alright, added :)

Comment: think that `RelativeLayout` has no `orientation` attribute, but else it looks ok.

Comment: @MartinZeitler You're right. RelativeLayouts don't have orientation attributes.

Comment: Song does not contain an array,  that's why it is not looping through it

Comment: Can you post your entire adapter class?

Comment: I have figured out the solution, I will be going through how I solved it a little later today. :)

Comment: Who is going to be awarded the bounty now that the question is solved? ;)

Comment: it will eventually be removed from the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your json structure.  In this situation, you'd want to be using a json array for the songs, and likely have a `Song` object.  Right now, they're likely parsed out as just an individual "song" which is really a `String`.  Something like the following json structure would be a start to something that would work as intended:

```
  "DjSunGazer" : {
    "songs" : [
      { "id" : "-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2", "name" : "Ginuwine - So Anxious" },
      { "id" : "-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI", "name" : "Ginuwine - So Anxious" },
      { "id" : "-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz", "name" : "Ginuwine - So Anxious" },
      { "id" : "-LmHrpZzOKOtY_8AGQ_S", "name" : "Rick Ross - Gold Roses (feat. Drake) }"
    ]
  }
```

I'd still recommend updating the json structure further, so it's easier to parse.  Right now it seems like you're including the artist's name as the key value for the song set, which I could see also causing problems or making things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: If i show my original code used for inserting into the database, could you show an example on how to achieve this structure?

Comment: This appears likely, because those nodes should have `{}` instead of `""`... adding model classes, alike `Playlist` or `Song` would also reduce the effort when reading it.

Comment: @beastlyCoder sure, I suppose.  I feel like it should be pretty much there, but I can update later today/tomorrow with further detail on the firebase side...

Comment: Thank you, I will post how I'm adding the information

Answer (score 1):

Complete and valid JSON file according to your need.

```
{"DjSunGazer": {
"songs": [{
"-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2 ": "Blaya - Cash ",
"-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI": "Blaya - Cash",
"-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz": "Taylor Swift - You Need to Calm Down"},{
"-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2 ": "Blaya - Cash ",
"-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI": "Blaya - Cash",
"-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz": "Taylor Swift - You Need to Calm Down"},{
"-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2 ": "Blaya - Cash ",
"-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI": "Blaya - Cash",
"-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz": "Taylor Swift - You Need to Calm Down"},{
"-LmHrkYkU1qD2GND9wY2 ": "Blaya - Cash ",
"-LmHrlalIVUStU6nqBJI": "Blaya - Cash",
"-LmHrmRRXy4UYoF7DNZz": "Taylor Swift - You Need to Calm Down"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my solution to use a custom firebase adapter. This helped fix my issue of adding each child view manually.

```
    songNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    mProfileDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)Aft
        {

            mProfileDatabase.child(djName).child("song")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            List<String> sArr = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                sArr.add(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                            }

                            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> songCounts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                            for(int i = 0; i < sArr.size(); i++)
                            {
                                String eachSong = sArr.get(i);
                                if(songCounts.containsKey(eachSong))
                                {
                                    int count = songCounts.get(eachSong);
                                    songCounts.put(eachSong, count + 1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    songCounts.put(eachSong, 1);
                                }
                            }
                            ArrayList<POJO> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> s:songCounts.entrySet()){
                                POJO pojo = new POJO(s.getKey(),s.getValue());
                                arrayList.add(pojo);
                            }

                            CustomRecyclerAdapter adapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(DjLanding.this,arrayList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the definition of my Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<POJO> personUtils;

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<POJO> personUtils) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personUtils = personUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.djname_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(personUtils.get(position));
        POJO pu = personUtils.get(position);
        holder.djNameView.setText(pu.getName());
        holder.badge.setText(pu.getCount()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personUtils.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView djNameView;
        public TextView badge;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            djNameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_result_dj);
            badge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_badge);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my plain old java class:

```
public class POJO
{
    String name;
    Integer count;

    public POJO(String name, Integer count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Hariom!